# Cannot convert a pointer when reading the size of a view frame

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I used the code below to read the size of a NSView

```
NSSize size =[[myView frame] size];
```

but Xcode reported error

```
can not convert a pointer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`frame` returns `NSRect`, which is a structure, not an object.  You can't send a message to a structure.  You want:

```
NSSize size = [myView frame].size;
```

Or perhaps clearer:

```
NSRect rect = [myView frame];
NSSize size = rect.size;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-frame` method returns a struct, which has the `NSSize` member you want. Try instead:

```
NSSize size = [myView frame].size;
```